# Prevent text crossing box wrapper

Tags: css

As shown in the image longer text in header `h2` exceeds box wrapper on smaller screens like mobiles. How to solve this?

[image]

```css
#toc {
    background: #eaf9f8;
    padding: 5px 0 2px;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
}

#toc h2 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 20px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="toc"><h2 class="db2">How to integrate blaaa bla into bla</h2></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have To just add `word-wrap: break-word;` in h2 element

```css
#toc {
    background: #eaf9f8;
    padding: 5px 0 2px;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
}

#toc h2 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 20px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    margin-right: 15px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="toc"><h2 class="db2">How to integrate blaaa bla into bla</h2></div>
```